# Compare Array [Triplets]

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

I'm trying to complete this

[image]

a = [5, 6, 7]
 b = [3, 6, 10]

Now, let's compare each individual score:

```
a[0] > b[0], so Alice receives  point.
a[1] == b[1], so nobody receives a point.
a[2] < b[2] , so Bob receives  point.
```

Alice's comparison score is 1, and Bob's comparison score is 1. Thus, we have to print 1 1 (Alice's comparison score followed by Bob's comparison score) on a single line.

I did it by this way:

```
var a = [5, 6, 7]
var b = [3, 6, 10]

let pointsAlice = (a[0] > b[0] ? 1: 0) + (a[1] > b[1] ? 1: 0) + (a[2] > b[2] ? 1: 0)

let pointsBob = (a[0] < b[0] ? 1: 0) + (a[1] < b[1] ? 1: 0) + (a[2] < b[2] ? 1: 0)

print("\(pointsAlice) \(pointsBob)")
```

But it is showing as an incorrect answer(Hackerrank).
Is my way correct or is there any other way to solve this ?

Comment: It's worth to show original problem description

Comment: @MBo https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Comment: Looks right. Are you sure in correct input treatment and output formatting?

Comment: No trying this for the first time. When I run the code it shows correct but after submission it shows wrong answer.

Comment: And you can read text file with two lines of predefined format?

Comment: Please show your complete code, in particular how you read the input data a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2.

Comment: Just take input for a/b instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: @vish4071 How to take it as input ?

Comment: Use functions like `readLine()` or `NSString(...)`

Answer (score 5):

Please try this ...

```
let a = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").flatMap { Int($0) }
let b = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").flatMap { Int($0) }
let aResult = zip(a, b).filter(>).count
let bResult = zip(b, a).filter(>).count

//Final Result Status 
print(aResult, bResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess u concentrated on explanation more :p
Try this:

```
let arrA = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map{ Int($0)! }
let arrB = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map{ Int($0)! }

var aliceScore = 0
var bobScore = 0

for index in 0...2{
    if (arrA[index] > arrB[index]){
        aliceScore += 1
    }
    if (arrA[index] < arrB[index]){
        bobScore += 1
    }
}
print("\(aliceScore)" + " " + "\(bobScore)")
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution. Trying to learn how the reduce func works.

> ```
> func compareTriplets(a: [Int], b: [Int]) -> [Int] {
>    var total = [0,0]
>
>    for x in 0..<a.count {
>       if a[x] > b[x] {
>          total[0] += 1
>       } else if a[x] < b[x] {
>         total[1] += 1
>       }
>    }
>    return  aTotal   
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use higher order functions like reduce?

```
let a = [5, 6, 7]
let b = [3, 6, 10]

let pointsAlice = zip(a, b).reduce(0, combine: { $0 + ($1.0 > $1.1 ? 1 : 0) } )
let pointsBob = zip(b, a).reduce(0, combine: { $0 + ($1.0 > $1.1 ? 1 : 0) } )

print("\(pointsAlice) \(pointsBob)") // 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not hard code like this

```
(a[0] > b[0] ? 1: 0) + (a[1] > b[1] ? 1: 0) + (a[2] > b[2] ? 1: 0)
```

Imagine if the array has 1,000 or more elements!!!

I think the simplest solution is:

```
var alicePoints = 0
var bobPoints = 0

for i in 0..<A.count {
    if A[i] > B[i] {
        alicePoints += 1
    } else if A[i] < B[i] {
        bobPoints += 1
    }
}

print("\(alicePoints)  \(bobPoints)")
```

And the more elegant solution is the one from @koropok above (I upated for Swift 3.x)

```
let bobPoints = zip(B, A).reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.0 > $1.1 ? 1 : 0) }
let alicePoints = zip(A, B).reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.0 > $1.1 ? 1 : 0) }

print("\(alicePoints)  \(bobPoints)")
```

Comment: I've gone through the Problem in HackerRank, the tricky part is you have to write code to get the input, not hard-code. So, instead of decrale the arrays

Comment: I've gone through the Problem in HackerRank, the tricky part is you have to write code to get the input, not hard-code. So, instead of decrale the arrays yourself, put following code: 
let A = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map{ Int($0)! } 
let B = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map{ Int($0)! }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated Answer for comparing Triplets

Let's say if we have

```
var a = [5, 6, 7]
var b = [3, 6, 10]
```

**Then**

```
// compareTriplets function
func compareTriplets(a: [Int], b: [Int]) -> [Int] {

let bobPoints = zip(b, a).reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.0 > $1.1 ? 1 : 0) }
let alicePoints = zip(a, b).reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.0 > $1.1 ? 1 : 0) }

print("Points earned by Alice and Bob : \(alicePoints)  \(bobPoints)")

return [alicePoints, bobPoints]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
`return [zip(a, b).reduce(0) {$0 + ($1.0 > $1.1 ? 1 : 0)},
         zip(b, a).reduce(0) {$0 + ($1.0 > $1.1 ? 1 : 0)}]`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In python, without considering the constraints proposed(ab >= 1 & ab<=100):

```
def compareTriplets(a, b):
    i = 0
    score = [0,0]

    while i < 3:
        if a[i] > b[i]:
            score[0] = score[0] + 1
        elif a[i] < b[i]:
            score[1] = score[1] + 1
        i = i + 1

     return score
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*.;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args)   {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int klice=0;
        int bob=0;
        int a[]=new int[n];
        int b[]=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            b[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(a[i]>b[i]){
                klice++;
            } else if(b[i]>a[i]){
                bob++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(klice +" "+ bob);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged with the Swift language, not Java. Your answer is off-topic.